# Sorting by date with extra text in field

Tags: jquery, date, sorting, datatables

Hi im trying to sort a field by date (UK) and have it working using the following code:

```
/* Datatables */
$("#tasks").dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "aoColumns": [{
        "bSortable": false
    },
    null,
    null,
    null, {
        "sType": "date-uk"
    }]
});
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
    "sSortable": "header",
        "sWrapper": "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"
});
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "date-uk-pre": function (a) {
        var ukDatea = a.split("/");
        return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
    },
        "date-uk-asc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
        "date-uk-desc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
/* End */
```

What i want to do is show the date and then have some text after it e.g.

22/08/2013 (Due in 5 days)

Obviously it breaks sorting, is there a way to ignore the stuff in the brackets and sort by date correctly?

Comment: you could show it as a tooltip.

Comment: how can i do this because each row would need a unique id wouldnt it?

Comment: <td title="4 days ago">22/08/2013</td>

Comment: I believe you can wrap the date in a span, and extract the span contents from `a` for comparison.

Comment: Is this doable using bootstraps popover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres how to do it using tooltips in bootstrap

```
        echo "<td id=\"popover-" . $row["id"] . "\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"$daysremaining days\">" . $row["due"] . "</td>";


        tasks.$("[id^=popover-]").tooltip({
            placement: "right"
        });
```